# Windows 10 is asking for a password even though the option is unchecked

Tags: windows-10, passwords

I unchecked the option to have Windows 10 ask for a password. It worked for a day or two but now it's requiring a password again upon waking up or rebooting--even though the option is still unchecked. I made a registry change that was suggested and it has not worked. How can I get Windows 10 to stop ignoring my changes?

Answer (score 0):

To disable the wakeup password prompt, press the <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> shortcut to open the Settings app. 
Then select "Accounts" → "Sign-in option", select "Never" from the "Require sign-in" option drop-down list.

[image: Require sign-in]